# Repo Sync to start with SDK 2012

Tags: android, git, sdk, cygwin, repository

So that's what I got after a repo sync. Sorry for sounding naive but how do I get the source code now? It's been stuck on a line for a few hours now. The last lines that appeared are:

```
 .
 .
 .     
 [new tag]   android-sdk-4.0.3-tools_r1 -> android-sdk-4.0.3-tools_r1
 [new tag]   android-sdk-4.0.3_r16.0.1 -> android-sdk-4.0.3_r16.0.1
 [new tag]   android-sdk-4.0.3_r20 -> android-sdk-4.0.3_r20
 [new tag]   android-sdk-support_r11 -> android-sdk-support_r11
```

And that is it. No indication of whether or not it's finished with the repo sync so I'm assuming that perhaps it's stuck? If so, how do I get it to resume again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/Prelpj-C58c), I suppose you are dpong on Cygwin something similar to:

```
mkdir android-4.0.3_r1
mkdir android-4.0.3_r1
cd android-4.0.3_r1
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync -f 2>&1 | tee outfile.txt
```

At the time, the solution was:

> I think I solved my problem.
>   I started again from the beginning and, this time, when I ran the '`repo init`' command and was prompted for my username: I just entered a one-word name.
>   In the past I entered my first and last name separated by a space. The rest went smoothly.

I would also recommend making those git commands in a DOS shell session, using **[msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full%20installer%20official%20git)**, instead of relying on an old git in a Cygwin session.